# База данных SQLite3 python

Tags: python, sqlite3

Имеется бд(SQLite) и яп python. в бд есть столбец с user_id и 7 столбцов с данными. Нужно у всех пользователей переместить данные на 1 столбец влево(1 столбец чистим, из 2 столбца в 1 столбец, из 3 столбца во 2 и т.д.). Это нужно сделать программно т.к. нужно делать регулярно по времени. Вопрос заключается в том, что можно ли как-то перекинуть сразу все или надо отдельно у каждого пользователя перезаписывать данные?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте через запрос `UPDATE` сделать присваивание столбцам

*Вместо `table_name` название вашей таблицы. Вместо `column1`-`column7` названия ваших столбцов. В `...` продолжаете перебор присваивания. Вместо `null` может быть другое значение, соответствующее столбцу, если его значение обязательное*

Пример:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column7 = column6, column6 = column5, ..., column2 = column1, column1 = null
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Sukamu, пожалуйста :)